# How can get the first dimension in a two-dimensional array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

How can get the first dimension in a two-dimensional array in swift,what I mean is like this:
Here is a two-dimensional array with the type of string:

```
[["1","2"],["4","5"],["8","9"]]
```

what I want is array like this:

```
["1","4","8"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke the [`first` instance property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1689165-first) on each sub-array as part of a [`compactMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2957701-compactmap) invocation of the outermost array.

```
let arr = [["1", "2"], ["4", "5"], ["8", "9"]]
let firstElements = arr.compactMap { $0.first } // ["1", "4", "8"]
```

Note however that `first` is an `Optional` property, that is `nil` for empty collections, and that a `nil` result in transform of the `compactMap(_:)` invocation will be removed. E.g.:

```
let arr = [["1", "2"], [], ["8", "9"]]
let firstElements = arr.compactMap { $0.first } // ["1", "8"]
```

For the general case, accessing the *nth* index in each sub-array, you can make use of the non-optional [`subscript(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1540606-subscript) accessor as part of a [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017520-map) invocation on the outermost array, carefully noting however that an attempt to access a non-existing element (*index out of bounds*) will lead to a run-time exception.

```
let arr = [["1", "2"], ["4", "5"], ["8", "9"]]
let idx = 1

// proceed only if idx is a valid index for all sub-arrays
if idx >= 0 && (!arr.contains { idx >= $0.count }) {
    let subElements = arr.map { $0[idx] } // ["2", "5", "9"]
    // ...
}
else {
    // this would correspond to an index that is invalid in at
    // at least one of the sub-arrays.
}
```

Alternatively, you could simply filter out sub-array subscript accesses that would correspond to index out of bounds, e.g. using `compactMap(_:)`:

```
let arr = [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5"], ["8", "9", "10"]]
let idx = 2
let subElements = arr
    .compactMap { 0..<$0.count ~= idx ? $0[idx] : nil } // ["3", "10"]
```

Comment: @Sweeper as `first` is an `Optional` property I went with `compactMap` (or the resulting array will be one of `[String?]`). For the general case (nth element), we could use the subscript instead and use `map`, but should then gate out-of-index access prior to applying the transform.

Comment: Another variation: `arr.compactMap { $0.dropFirst(idx).first } `

Comment: @MartinR very nice use of `dropFirst(_:)`! I didn't know the empty sequence property of it; _"If the number of elements to drop exceeds the number of elements in the collection, the result is an empty subsequence."_. Could incur and extra cost though for a large index if the the sub-arrays are large (_Complexity: O(n), where n is the number of elements to drop from the beginning of the collection._).

Comment: @dfri: I would *assume* that the cost is O(1) for an array (or any RandomAccessCollection), one would have to look up the implementation.

Comment: @MartinR yes it's curious that it's described as O(n) also for the `dropFirst(_:)` of the `Array` documentation; maybe a copy-paste mistake from sequence -> array docs (I've seen those before). I could have a look and submit a PR to update the docs in case it's actually O(1) for an array/random access collection.

Comment: @MartinR I _think_ the [implemention of `Collection`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L1334) is used also for `Array`/`RandomAccessCollection`, in which case the cost of `dropFirst(_:)` derives from the cost of `index(_:offsetBy:limitedBy)` and `subscript(bounds:)`, where the former has an O(1) implementation for `RandomAccessCollection` and the latter is just a slice (O(1)). So the docs:complexity for `dropFirst(_:)` of `Collection` should probably be updated to include an if clause, similar to the `index(...)` implementations of `Collection`.

Comment: Yes, I came to the same conclusion.